# Rails 6: Can a model be aware of changes made to one of its has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a model `Profile` with many `gallery_items`.

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  has_many :gallery_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_items, allow_destroy: true
```

I want to fire code in `Profile` any time a gallery item is changed. Is there a way to do this without amending the `GalleryItem` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after_touch` hook on the Profile.  Just be sure to denote that the GalleryItem touches the Profile in its association.

```
class GalleryItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile, touch: true
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :gallery_items
  after_touch :my_fancy_method

  private
    def my_fancy_method
      puts 'Doing some stuff after a GalleryItem was created/updated'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6 has only 4 possible ActiveRecord **Association Callbacks** at the moment: `before_add, after_add, before_remove and after_remove`.

Source: [Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+callbacks)

Unfortunately as the names themselves suggest, they are not aware of updates or changes to the associated objects, so if you to be aware of updates on gallery items small tweaks need to be done to the GalleryItem class as Jared suggested for example, or using an `after_update`.